# Are Gmail email Templates accessible by Google Apps Script (GAS)?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

The Gmail email templates are a relatively new feature, that need to be enabled in Gmail > Settings > Advanced > Templates => Enable

> Templates Turn frequent messages into templates to save time.
> Templates can be created and inserted through the "More options" menu
> in the compose toolbar. You can also create automatic replies using
> templates and filters together.

Do you know if those email Templates can be accessed by Google Apps Script?

[image: Gmail Templates screenshot]

Screenshot link: [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xeYU.png)

Comment: I don't know about templates but drafts can be accessed via google apps script.

Comment: @Cooper thank you, good to know about drafts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The templates are just email drafts. So just query for email drafts as you normally would.